# Python: extract a column of data from several text files

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I have been scratching my head pretty hard on this one. I have several text files, all in the same format:

```
   99.00%   2874    2874    U   0   unclassified
  1.00% 29  0   R   1   root
  1.00% 29  0   R1  131567    cellular organisms
  1.00% 29  0   D   2759        Eukaryota
  1.00% 29  0   D1  33154         Opisthokonta
  1.00% 29  0   K   4751            Fungi
  1.00% 29  0   K1  451864            Dikarya
```

I want to extract the 6th column from all these files and print it to a new file.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import sys
import os
import glob

# Usage: python extract_species.py path/to/folder > output.txt

def extractSpecies(fileContent, allSpecies):
    for line in fileContent.split('\n'):
        allSpecies.append(line.split('\t')[0])

def file_get_contents(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read()

def listdir_fullpath(d):
    return [os.path.join(d, f) for f in os.listdir(d)]

allFiles = listdir_fullpath(sys.argv[1]) # List all files in the folder provided by system arg.

# Read all files and store content in memory
filesContent = [] # a list is created with one item per file.
for filePath in allFiles:
    filesContent.append(file_get_contents(filePath))

# Extract all species and create a unique list
allSpecies = []
for fileContent in filesContent:
    extractSpecies(fileContent, allSpecies)

print(allSpecies)
```

But this code provides only the values of the first column of data:

```
99.00%   1.00%   1.00%   1.00%   1.00%   1.00%   1.00%
```

If I remove the [0] argument in line 7 (after "allSpecies.append(line.split('\t')"), then the object allSpecies contains all the data in the files.

```
[' 99.00%', '2874', '2874', 'U', '0', 'unclassified'] ['  1.00%', '29', '0', 'R', '1', 'root'] ['  1.00%', '29', '0', 'R1', '131567', '  cellular organisms'] ['  1.00%', '29', '0', 'D', '2759', '    Eukaryota'] ['  1.00%', '29', '0', 'D1', '33154', '      Opisthokonta'] etc
```

I thought I could simply change the [0] by the number of the column I am interested in (from 1 to 5), but no, if I do that I get an error saying:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Which really baffles me. There must be something I really don't get: how can I extract the value of the first column but not of any other column. Any suggestion is welcome at this point...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right path with removing the zero. You can then iterate through allSpecies and grab the columns by the index.

```
column6 = []
for x in allSpecies:
    column6.append(allSpecies[x][5])
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: OK, finally got it: it was a simple format error. The file had an extra new line at the end which messed with the data extraction. Stupid to spend so much time on such a simple mistake, but I guess you learn something every time...